# Selected ListBox item to Variable

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, listbox, event-handling

I've been trying for 2 days now to save the selected value from a listBox to a variable. All suggestions I can find do not work, and the only suggestion that actually does work has been discouraged from using. Can someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have made the code as simple as possible for this posting. Both WPF and C# that is. In de code I show different suggestions of how it could work which I have found on this and other forums.

1.
Test 01 and Test 02 do compile alright but they both give me the same wrong result.

result in TextBox: *System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: ListBox Item 02*

Looking at the result and the code I can kind of understand the result for 'Test 2'. It looks like a reference to what I actually want and 'SelectedItem' Could suggest this. But then in 'Test 01' I get the same result but I am asking for value instead of reference. Why?

2.
The most common suggested method is 'Test 04'. Everything I have tried gives me more or less the same error.

Error message: *Compiler Error CS1061: 'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'GetItemText' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).*

It is also the shortest and simplest method so I would really like to get this method to work. Maybe I have done something wrong somewhere else (Settings in VS 2015 Maybe???). I have seen the same message before, but I was able to work around it that time.

3.
And just before decided to post this here I wanted to try 1 more thing. 'Test 03' was something I saw in another post on this website with the comment that this is not the way to do it. Ok, the original post has been edited so I do not know what was originally published, but this is the one and only thing that actually did work until now. The original post was advised against though.

I am new to WPF and C#. Normally it may take me time to find out how to do things but I get there eventually, but this time I do not really understand what has happened and something tells me that I am doing something wrong. Can someone be so kind to elaborate on one, some or all of the items outlined above? I got it working now, but is this the best way to go about this?

Code Behind (C#):

```
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    namespace NLTrader
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ///textBox.Text = listBox.SelectedValue.ToString();                         ///Test 01
                ///textBox.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();                          ///Test 02
                textBox.Text = ((ListBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();      ///Test 03
                ///textBox.Text = listBox.GetItemText();                                    ///Test 04
            }
        }
    }
```

WPF Code:

```
    <Window x:Class="NLTrader.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NLTrader"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="555" Width="900">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel 
                x:Name="mainSettings"
                Grid.Row="0">
                <ListBox 
                    x:Name="listBox"
                    SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item 01</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item 02</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item 03</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox 
                x:Name="textBox"
                Grid.Row="1">
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Edit: p.s. I just notice that in order to see the comments in the code identifying which is 'Test 01, 'Test 02", 'Test 03' and 'Test 04' you will need to move the scroll bar to the right.

Edit: I also just notice that when I place the above working code in the code where it needs to be (different project) I also get an error. Last bit of euphoria down the drain... lol.

Structure is very very similar. c# code is as follows.

```
        public void ListingAccounts_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxAccountSettingsAccountName.Text = ((ListBoxItem)ListingAccounts.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
        }
```

Error Message: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in NLTrader.exe
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.*

[Screenshot from VS2015 Debugger Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwnz1.png)

So now I am even more at a loss than I already was. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it say when you hover over the `SelectedItem`? If it's `string` (and the InvalidCastException seems to say so), you should be able to do

```
 textBoxAccountSettingsAccountName.Text = ListingAccounts.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

I'd suggest a look at http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/ if you haven't yet.

Just a note: The [SelectionChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.addeditems(v=VS.100).aspx) does have the selection, it's there! :P

EDIT: I can't comment, but just a warning on @funk's answer, `e.AddedItems[0]` will throw an indexoutofRange exception when the selection is deselected (as nothing is 'added') so you should use `e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault() and check for null if you use his solution. The same goes for this solution I suppose, SelectedItem will be null when deselection happens

Comment: Hi Eric,I have tried it immediately but now get the following message;

Comment: Compiler Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: try appending ToString() (like ListingAccounts.SelectedItem.ToString())

Comment: When hovering over the 'SelectedItem' I get the following message. object System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectedItem { get; set; } Gets or sets the first item in the current selection or returns null if the selection is empty

Comment: Well, that's okay. I forgot that it's an object by default. Shouldn't matter if you call ToString

Comment: ok, it works. Like in the original posting above now. But I made a mistake or simply the wrong assumption. In the WPF I had declared the 3 items in the WPF code itself for sake of simplicity. In the original code these values are inserted by C#. I guess I should close this one and open a new post but I am new here. What do you suggest?

Comment: Ok, it all works now. textBoxAccountSettingsAccountName.Text = ListingAccounts.SelectedItem.ToString(); is the solution. I forgot the brackets at the end. Do you know why my method worked when the listbox values are declared in WPF but does not work when declared through C#?

Comment: I'm not exactly a veteran myself if you look at the points :). There's a 40-minute delay on asking questions which you passed, so I'd suggest just asking a new one

Comment: I can't see the code you used to declare in c# so I can't be sure, but I think it could be you skipped initializing the collection?

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes as I ran into this issue as well today. Two things I needed to do that were pretty simple:
1. Add an assembly reference in my project: System.Windows.Forms
2. Using tutorial posted by Eric van der Toorn, I implemented the code as follows;

```
{

  if (upldListBox.SelectedItem != null)
  {
    string uploadFile = upldListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    exec.UploadToStHost(uploadFile);
  }
}
```

Hoping this helps.